# Online backup solution

Tags: backup, online-backup

I am looking for a backup solution to backup all my data (about 3-4TB).

I have look at many services out there, such as:

- http://www.backblaze.com/
- http://www.crashplan.com/

Those services look very good, and a reasonable price.

But I am worried about them because of incidents like this:

- http://jeffreydonenfeld.com/blog/2011/12/crashplan-online-backup-lost-my-entire-backup-archive/

I am wondering if there is any online back solution that offers a service level agreement (SLA) with compensation for data loss at a reasonable price (under $30 per month).

Or is there a good solution that offers a high enough level of redundancy to mitigate the risk?

Required:

- Offsite backup to prevent data loss in terms of fire/theft.
- Redundancy to protect the backup from corruption.
- A reasonable cost (< $30 per month).
- A SLA in case the service provider faults on its agreements.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is clearly off topic and falls under shopping recommendations. I just noticed it because of the meta question you asked earlier. As you can see from the answers, a different backup plan might be the solution for your actual problem though.

Comment: @slhck what site should I ask this on?

Comment: No Stack Exchange site would encourage shopping recommendations – that being said, you could ask your way 'round [chat] and see if anyone knows a service or could help you find one.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/), you are uploading your files to AWS infrastructure so failure rate is low. But according to their terms, you do not get compensation

> THE SERVICE OFFERINGS ARE PROVIDED “AS IS.” WE AND OUR AFFILIATES AND LICENSORS MAKE NO REPRESENTATIONS OR WARRANTIES OF ANY KIND, WHETHER EXPRESS, IMPLIED, STATUTORY OR OTHERWISE REGARDING THE SERVICE OFFERINGS OR THE THIRD PARTY CONTENT, INCLUDING ANY WARRANTY THAT THE SERVICE OFFERINGS OR THIRD PARTY CONTENT WILL BE UNINTERRUPTED, ERROR FREE OR FREE OF HARMFUL COMPONENTS, OR THAT ANY CONTENT, INCLUDING YOUR CONTENT OR THE THIRD PARTY CONTENT, WILL BE SECURE OR NOT OTHERWISE LOST OR DAMAGED

Comment: Well this is not really a considerable solution, especially because of Amazon's failure track record.

Comment: Please post some links to corroborate "Amazon's failure track record."

Comment: While not being extreamly significant, http://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/ that was one of the few cases that effected many of our customers.

Answer (score 2):

The first question one should answer when deciding on a backup strategy is "What is my recovery plan?"

I would separate your requirements and not have them all fulfilled by the same "provider", specifically the "redunandancy" and "online to protect against fire or theft" requirements.

I would buy a NAS or some simlar large storage device, backup to that locally. Then mirror that somewhere online, probably Amazon Glacier.

Redundancy is now achieved by having one copy local, one in the cloud.

Protection against theft or fire by the copy you have online.

And, of course, what is the data worth to you? Just 30 bucks a month?

Comment: My recovery plan is, as long as I can recover my data (I chose to backup) within 1 week (or even 1 month), its fine. "Just $30 per month", considering I could buy 2x 2TB portable hard drives per year for $30 per month, I think that is fair. And how is buying a NAS first, then backing up to Amazon better in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for online but due to the amount of data you may be hard pushed to get it for the cost.

Any way, just as a consideration this is what I do. I have a QNAP with 4 x 3 TB hard drives. 2 of which are set up as RAID - this means I actually can only stored 2 x 3TB (6 TB) because the other 2 hard drives are a mirror image (and please note, a mirror image includes mirroring corrupt data). The good thing about RAID and QNAP is it monitors the disc's life - as soon as it reports a disc is failing, bin it and stick in a new hard drive which then sync's to the other providing you 2 copies again! (and again, RAID is not foolproof but outside the scope of your question so I won't go into detail).

One a week, a program copies my PC to the machine (but I also have the ability to copy when I want). Since it's local, the back up is very fast as it only backs up amended / new files. Therefore, I have a copy on my PC, and 2 on the NAS drive (1 version mirrored). The good thing about a NAS is, you can power it down and take it with you. Yes, this is hassle but the only solution for me as I don't have an offsite copy.

It also means you're back up is not reliant on your ISP/Intenet connection, the remote back up site being up and running, and your data is in your control! You can check the backed up data to check integrity.

The only issue with my solution is as already stated, it's not online. If online is a 100% must then I guess this suggestion is useless. Again, I know this isn't a direct answer but maybe it's helpful.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't protect my data from fire or thief. And for the cost I am willing to pay 3x-10x the amount the solutions I found are offering.

Comment: I updated my answer, even though the last line said "high enough level of redundancy to mitigate the risk", which fire and theft is one of the most common risks.